# Finding a better way to do something

Tags: meaning, expressions, business-language

Suppose my boss asked me to complete a task, and the standard method takes a week of my time. But I did some research and I found another method, which only takes a day, but is equally good!

How would I refer to this without sounding like I cut corners? "Finding a shortcut", for example, might imply laziness.

Comment: Call it "optimizing".

Comment: Barmar's suggestion seems to fit like a glove.

Comment: I discovered a *better/faster* way ...

Comment: Perhaps the best way is not to tell him all at once. Start off by saying you have made a discovery which might save some time.

Comment: I'd comment that *optimizing* implies refining an existing process. So finding a different method would likely not be considered an optimization. it would be more like a *New and improved solution*.

Comment: Thanks all, should've clarified this was *intended* as a general question about something a lot of people come across especially in IT. I actually like "I discovered a better way" more than "optimise" because it seems more specific.

Comment: You could also use the "Scotty" approach. Tell him it will take a week, then surprise him with results in a day, basking in your brilliance.

Comment: If the standard method keeps you out of mischief for a whole week, your shortcut is evidently worse.

Comment: @Barmar Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: *Timesaving*, *timesaver*, *saving time*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of quality management, the desired result is achieved more *efficiently.*

The term *efficiency* is defined as ‘relationship between the result achieved and the resources used’.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[honed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hone)* the process

> [WITH OBJECT] Refine or perfect (something) over a period of time:
>   *she has taken numerous workshops to hone her skills over the years*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

You are now being more *Productive*. Your *Productivity* has increased.

Productivity can be defined as a measure of the efficiency of a person, machine, factory, system, etc., in converting inputs into useful outputs.

So for your example, if the standard or normal time to complete the task is five days (assuming a five day working week) and you have completed the task in one day: Your personal productivity for this task is %500 or alternatively you could say you have achieved a five-fold increase in productivity for the stated task.

And you now have an additional line for your CV.

Answer (score 0):

> **INNOVATE** *verb*: innovate; 3rd person present: innovates; past tense: innovated; past participle: innovated; gerund or present participle: innovating
>
> make changes in something established, especially by introducing new methods, ideas, or products. "the company's failure to diversify and innovate competitively"
>
> •introduce (something new, especially a product).
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=innovate+d&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=innovate+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l4j0i10.0.0.0.23995...........0.zbBEt0OmNu8&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **INNOVATION**
>
> Innovation is a new idea, device or process. Innovation can be viewed as the application of better solutions that meet new requirements, inarticulated needs, or existing market needs. This is accomplished through more effective products, processes, services, technologies, or ideas that are readily available to markets, governments and society. The term innovation can be defined as something original and more effective and, as a consequence, new, that "breaks into" the market or society.
>
> [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innovation)